# Cardinal power $\kappa^\kappa$. When is it equal to $2^\kappa$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Under what assumptions on an infinite cardinal $\kappa$ we have
$$\kappa^\kappa= 2^\kappa?$$

Please delete this question. I know the answer.

Comment: Once posting a question, it might be useful for future visitors. If you know the answer it is fine to post an answer on your own.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a repeat, and I know I've posted an answer. In fact, if $\lambda$ satisfies $2\leq \lambda \leq 2^{\kappa}$, then $\lambda^{\kappa}=2^{\kappa}$ by the same argument Asaf uses below.

Comment: These answers are about $\lambda^\kappa=2^\kappa$ for $2\le\lambda\le (\kappa^+)$: [Cardinal equalities: $\aleph_0^\mathfrak c=2^\mathfrak c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/36968#36999), [Is $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ smaller than or equal to $2^{\aleph_0}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110211#110249). @ArturoMagidin Maybe you meant one of those answers when you wrote that you posted an answer to this before?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming $\kappa$ is an ordinal the answer is *always*.

The reason is simple: by Cantor's theorem we have $2<\kappa<2^\kappa$, therefore using exponentiation laws: $$2^\kappa\le\kappa^\kappa\le\left(2^\kappa\right)^\kappa=2^{\kappa\cdot\kappa}=2^\kappa$$