# Proving $|A^A|=|2^A|$ for infinite $A$.

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cardinal power $\kappa^\kappa$. When is it equal to $2^\kappa$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134834/cardinal-power-kappa-kappa-when-is-it-equal-to-2-kappa)

How can one prove that $|A^A|=|2^A|$ for infinite $A$? (summary of proof or providing link with proof will also suffice.)
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $|2^A|\leq |A^A|$ and by Cantor-Bernstein theorem we are reduced to show that $|A^A|\leq |2^A|$. To see that, we use the fact that $|A\times A|=|A|$, applying Zorn lemma to $S:=\{(B,f), B\subset A, f\colon B\times B\to B\}$ with the partial order $(B_1,f_1)\leq (B_2,f_2)$ if $B_1\subset B_2$ and $f_{2\mid B_1}=f_1$. We also have $$|2^A|=|2^{A\times A}|=|(2^A)^A|$$
which gives what we wanted.

Comment: Is f 1-1 and onto? And we get what we wanted because |A^A|<=|(2^A)^A| using the fact that if A<=B then |A^C|<=|B^C|, right?

Comment: That, and the fact that $\lvert 2^A\rvert>\lvert A\rvert$ in the first place. :) I don't really get the part about Zorn's lemma though. What do you use it for?

Comment: because $|A^A|\leq |(2^A)^A|$.

Comment: @tomasz We use Zorn's Lemma to show that |AxA|=|A|

Comment: @Idan I see. I figured it is either a known result or one which should be proven more carefully. Also, the $f$ in $S$ should be bijective.