# Do we have $|\mathcal P(X)|=|X^X|$ in ZF?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

If we have an infinite set $|X|$, does $2^{|X|}=|X|^{|X|}$ hold in ZF? In the other words, is there a bijection between $\mathcal P(X)$ and $X^X$?

I understand that if we have well-order on $X$ then I can get $$2^{|X|} \le |X|^{|X|} \le 2^{|X\times X|} = 2^{|X|},$$
but this argument uses $|X\times X|=|X|$. (Which is true if I assume existence of a well-order on $X$, but this is not necessarily true in ZF.)

Am I correct in assuming that in ZF the above equality may fail? What would be a simple argument to show this?

---

I got interested in this after reading this in Noah Schweber's answer to: [What is $\aleph_0!$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2551471#2551482)

> And this can be simplified further: it turns out $\kappa^\kappa=2^\kappa$, always. Clearly we have $2^\kappa\le\kappa^\kappa$, and in the other direction $$\kappa^\kappa\le (2^\kappa)^\kappa=2^{\kappa\cdot\kappa}=2^\kappa.$$
>
> By the way, the equality $\kappa^\kappa=2^\kappa$ can be proved in ZF alone, the key point being that Cantor-Bernstein doesn't need choice.

I was able to find similar argument in: [Cardinal power $\kappa^\kappa$. When is it equal to $2^\kappa$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/134834), [Proving $|A^A|=|2^A|$ for infinite $A$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/182960) (In both cases the argument uses $\kappa\cdot\kappa=\kappa$ or $|A\times A|=|A|$.)

I had also look at Andreas Blass' answer to the related question [Cardinality of the permutations of an infinite set](https://mathoverflow.net/q/27785#86594). If I understood that answer correctly, $|\mathcal P(X)|=|X^X|$ can indeed fail in ZF. But maybe there is an easier argument if we are working with all functions (not just bijections).

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122778/when-does-aa-2a-without-the-axiom-of-choice

Comment: Also, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1660457/how-does-equality-mathfrakm-mathfrakm-2-mathfrakm-in-sfzf-rela

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'd guess this should be [dupehammered](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/dupehammer/info). (And I should have searched a bit better before asking.)

Comment: As you wish. :)

Comment: Just to give a quick answer, if $X$ is an amorphous set, then $X^X$ and $\mathcal P(X)$ are both Dedekind-finite, and therefore cannot be equal in size (since one is clearly larger than the other). I suspect the same should hold for any $\kappa$-amorphous set, and thus one can show that even $\sf DC_{<\kappa}$ is not enough for this proof.