# What is aleph-one to the power of aleph-null

Tags: cardinals

What is $\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}$?

Can anyone shed some light.
I'm not sure if this is provable or even has a value.
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Since $\aleph_1\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$, it follows that
$$2^{\aleph_0} \leq \aleph_1^{\aleph_0} \leq (2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0},$$
and hence we conclude that $\aleph_1^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0}$.

More generally, for any infinite cardinal $\kappa$, $2^{\kappa}=\lambda^{\kappa}$ for all cardinals $\lambda$ with $2\leq \lambda\leq \kappa^+$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36968/cardinal-equalities-aleph-0-mathfrak-c-2-mathfrak-c). Since $\aleph_1=(\aleph_0)^+$, the result also follows from that observation.

Note that some of the assertions above may involve or require the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: +1. To elaborate for the OP on the last line of this answer: while $\mathsf{ZF}$ alone proves the existence of a surjection from $2^{\aleph_0}$ to $(\aleph_1)^{\aleph_0}$ it does not prove the existence of an *injection* going the other way - or even an injection from $\aleph_1$ to $2^{\aleph_0}$. $\mathsf{ZF}$ *can* prove that each of $2^{\aleph_0}$ and $(\aleph_1)^{\aleph_0}$ surjects onto the other, but without choice we can't prove that "surjections both ways implies bijection" (while [injections both ways are enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem)).

Comment: @NoahSchweber: In fact, “surjections both ways implies bijection” implies the Axiom of  Countable Choice. [See this MO post and references therein](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38771/dual-schroeder-bernstein-theorem)

Comment: Of course, I just wanted to keep things snappy. (Until the OP's comfortable with AC on its own, bringing in its fragments is likely to just get messy.)

Comment: @Arturo I don’t see that result in the linked. All I see demonstrated in the references is that it implies every infinite set has a countable subset.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: ah, you are correct; Asaf corrected that impression in the comments, noting it is weaker than countable choice. Thank you.